# WSO2 Identity Server error con Active directory

Tags: wso2, activedirectory

Les paso a comentar el problema que tengo. Tengo instalado WSO2 IS 6.x en cluster con un balanceador de carga NGINX. Agregué un user store secundario desde carbon para conectarme a un Active Directory. El problema se me da porque puedo listar a todos los usuarios pero al momento de loguearme sela el siguiente error en los logs.

"Error trying to obtain a certificate from the client javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"

Puede que tenga que agregar el certificado del AD al keystore de wso2, aunque la conexión sea no segura por el port 389?

Les paso la configuracion del AD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://xxxxx:389</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=xxxx,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx</Property>
      <Property encrypted="true" name="ConnectionPassword">xxx</Property>
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx</Property>
      <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
      <Property name="GroupIDEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="GroupIdAttribute">objectGuid</Property>
      <Property name="UserIDAttribute">objectGuid</Property>
      <Property name="UserIdSearchFilter">(&amp;amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
      <Property name="UserDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
      <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="CaseInsensitiveUsername">true</Property>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=WSO2,DC=Com</Property>
      <Property name="GroupCreatedDateAttribute">whenCreated</Property>
      <Property name="GroupLastModifiedDateAttribute">whenChanged</Property>
      <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
      <Property name="RoleDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
      <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
      <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated.</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password pattern policy violated.</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="LDAPInitialContextFactory">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</Property>
      <Property name="DateAndTimePattern">[uuuuMMddHHmmss[,SSS][.SSS]X][uuuuMMddHHmmss[,SS][.SS]X][uuuuMMddHHmm[,S][.S]X]</Property>
      <Property name="BulkImportSupported">true</Property>
      <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
      <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
      <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
      <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="ReadTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="RetryAttempts">0</Property>
      <Property name="CountRetrieverClass"/>
      <Property name="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary">objectGuid</Property>
      <Property name="ClaimOperationsSupported">true</Property>
      <Property name="transformObjectGUIDToUUID">true</Property>
      <Property name="MembershipAttributeRange">1500</Property>
      <Property name="UserCacheExpiryMilliseconds"/>
      <Property name="UserDNCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="StartTLSEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionRetryDelay">120000</Property>
      <Property name="ImmutableAttributes">objectGuid,whenCreated,whenChanged</Property>
      <Property name="TimestampAttributes">whenChanged,whenCreated</Property>
      <Property name="DomainName">xxx</Property>
      <Property name="Description"/>
</UserStoreManager>
```

Cualquier ayuda que me den se los agradezco!!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Sin ver cómo está configurado el WSO2 IS para conectar a AD, es difícil decir nada. Por ejemplo, es posible que la autenticación requiera que las credenciales viajen con SSL o TLS, pero no tenemos cómo saber nada de tu entorno. Lo otro: yo no tendría eso viajando no seguro, pero eso soy yo :)

Comment: Les cuento un poco mas, actualmente tenemos un wso2 is 5.xx funcionando con la misma configuracion de AD , pero en un solo nodo sin balanceado. No se si esto sirva de algo